# 0 < 0 evaluates to true?

Tags: objective-c, ios, c

This is crazy. What sort of mad dimension am I in?!

Please help me make sense of this:
[image: Madness!]

In my original problem, both are floats, but this still passes!

Comment: Did you do a full clean & build? Maybe you're running an old version of your code that's out of sync with your source code.

Comment: Are you sure that it's really evaluating to true? Does the same code appear anywhere else? I've been surprised in the past by compiler optimizations where it identified common blocks of code and refactored them, resulting in seemingly impossible program flows when tracing in a debugger...

Comment: Looks like a surprised smiley with a nose rotated to the side.

Comment: I'm confused....why are you even using that?  If that is really your code what is the reasoning for it?  Why not just put && NO?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, post the code itself.  It's easier to read and can be copy-pasted if necessary.

Comment: Can't reproduce this. Have you tried to reproduce the problem in a separate piece of code?

Comment: "In my original problem, both are floats" Are they also literals, or are they variables (that you have computed somewhere ?) This can make a world of a dfference. Please post the _actual_ code.

Comment: Whoa, lots of activity :) My mistake posting a screenshot instead of the source @oli; I just wanted to get it up here quick before I left, and the curline in the debugger seemed like a succinct way to sum up my problem. To answer you @nos, one of them was a computed value in my original code. Doing a full clean, restarting, and building from scratch seemed to do the trick, though. You really should have submitted an ansnwer @pablo! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

Was compiler code optimization enabled in this execution? If so, chances are the compiler flattened a loop or did some tricks to speed up code which could cause that the source in the editor no longer corresponds to the actual binary being executed. In these cases you may witness stepping "backwards" in a function and other weird things. Try putting an `NSLog` in that branch, I'd be very surprised if it got hit.

Other option is what others have already mentioned, that is, the source and the binary are out of sync, which can usually be resolved by a massive clean-rebuild.